# Assign Value in List<T> when T model itself has List<T> as a property

Tags: c#, list, class

i need a coding help. I have 3 classes SiteMapSection (holds sectionUrl and list of SiteMapSubSection), SiteMapSubSection (holds subSectionUrl and list of SiteMapArticle) and SiteMapArticle. Here is the class structure.

```
public class SiteMapSection
{
    public string sectionUrl { get; set; }
    public List<SiteMapSubSection> subSection { get; set; }
}

public class SiteMapSubSection
{
    public string subSectionUrl { get; set; }
    public List<SiteMapArticle> article { get; set; }
}

public class SiteMapArticle
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'm using above class as a Model to assign values:

```
        var siteMapSection = new List<SiteMapSection>();
        DL.SectionArticle sa = new NewsFeed.BusinessTier.DataAccessLayer.SectionArticle();

        foreach (BE.Section section in BL.Sections.Find(websiteId, parentSectionId))
        {
            int sectionId = section.Id;
            siteMapSection.Add(new SiteMapSection { sectionUrl = BL.Sections.VirtualPath(section) + ".aspx" });

            Debug.WriteLine(siteMapSection[0].sectionUrl);

            foreach (BE.Section subsection in BL.Sections.Find(websiteId, sectionId))
            {
                int subSectionId = subsection.Id;
                var smss = new List<SiteMapSubSection>();
                smss.Add(new SiteMapSubSection { subSectionUrl = BL.Sections.VirtualPath(subsection) + ".aspx" });

                Debug.WriteLine(smss[0].subSectionUrl);

                var articles = sa.GetArticlesForSection(websiteId, subSectionId, 10);
                foreach (var article in articles)
                {
                    var sma = new List<SiteMapArticle>();
                    sma.Add(new SiteMapArticle { url = BL.Sections.VirtualPath(subsection) + "/" + article.Code + "-" + UrlEncoding.ArticleEncode(article.Headline) + ".aspx" });

                    Debug.WriteLine(sma[0].url);
                }
            }
        }
```

Above code works great only the output by Debug.WriteLine(). But, when i hover on "var siteMapSection" it shows 'sectionUrl' and 'subSection' is null. This is because i've added values in separate variables inside foreach. How to modify code to get it in (when i hover on var siteMapSection) something like:

```
    siteMapSection
      [0]sectionUrl = "abc.com"
         subSection
         [0]subSectionUrl = "ced.com"
            [0]url = "zya.com"
            [1]url = "sd.com"
            [2]url = "ab.in"
            ::::::::::::::::
         [1]subSectionUrl = "abd.org"
            [0]url = "yy.in"
            ::::::::::::::::
         :::::::::::::::::::
      [1]sectionUrl = "yep.com"
         subSection
         [0]subSectionUrl = "ced.com"
            [0]url = "zya.com"
            [1]url = "sd.com"
            [2]url = "ab.in"
            ::::::::::::::::
         [1]subSectionUrl = "abd.org"
            [0]url = "yy.in"
            ::::::::::::::::
         :::::::::::::::::::
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the collections in the variables `section` and `subsection` and add to them directly.

```
            var siteMapSection = new List<SiteMapSection>();
            DL.SectionArticle sa = new NewsFeed.BusinessTier.DataAccessLayer.SectionArticle();

            foreach (BE.Section section in BL.Sections.Find(websiteId, parentSectionId))
            {
                int sectionId = section.Id;
                var mySection = new SiteMapSection();
                mySection.sectionUrl = BL.Sections.VirtualPath(section) + ".aspx";
                mySection.subSection = new List<SiteMapSubSection>();

                siteMapSection.Add(mySection);// NOTICE CHANGE HERE

                //Debug.WriteLine(siteMapSection[0].sectionUrl);

                foreach (BE.Section subsection in BL.Sections.Find(websiteId, sectionId))
                {
                    int subSectionId = subsection.Id;

                    var mySubSection = new SiteMapSubSection();
                    mySubSection.subSectionUrl = BL.Sections.VirtualPath(subsection) + ".aspx";
                    mySubSection.article = new List<SiteMapArticle>();
enter code here
                    mySection.subSection.Add(mySubSection);// NOTICE CHANGE HERE

                    //Debug.WriteLine(smss[0].subSectionUrl);

                    var articles = sa.GetArticlesForSection(websiteId, subSectionId, 10);
                    foreach (var article in articles)
                    {

                        mySubSection.article.Add(new SiteMapArticle { url = BL.Sections.VirtualPath(subsection) + "/" + article.Code + "-" + UrlEncoding.ArticleEncode(article.Headline) + ".aspx" });// NOTICE CHANGE HERE

                        //Debug.WriteLine(sma[0].url);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: subSection, article not found. Do I need to declare them like this var subSection = new List<SiteMapSubSection>() and var article = new List<SiteMapArticle>() before foreach starts? Tried this, still shows not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var siteMapSection = new List<SiteMapSection>();
        DL.SectionArticle sa = new NewsFeed.BusinessTier.DataAccessLayer.SectionArticle();

        foreach (BE.Section section in BL.Sections.Find(websiteId, parentSectionId))
        {
            int sectionId = section.Id;
            var siteMap=new SiteMapSection { sectionUrl = BL.Sections.VirtualPath(section) + ".aspx" };


            Debug.WriteLine(siteMap.sectionUrl);
        var smss = new List<SiteMapSubSection>();
            foreach (BE.Section subsection in BL.Sections.Find(websiteId, sectionId))
            {
                int subSectionId = subsection.Id;
                var sms=new SiteMapSubSection { subSectionUrl = BL.Sections.VirtualPath(subsection) + ".aspx" };
        Debug.WriteLine(smss[0].subSectionUrl);                



        var sma = new List<SiteMapArticle>();
                var articles = sa.GetArticlesForSection(websiteId, subSectionId, 10);
                foreach (var article in articles)
                {
                    var sm= new SiteMapArticle { url = BL.Sections.VirtualPath(subsection) + "/" + article.Code + "-" +             UrlEncoding.ArticleEncode(article.Headline) + ".aspx" };  
                    sma.Add(sm);

                    Debug.WriteLine(sm.url);
                }
        sms.article=sma;
        smss.Add(sms);
            }
        siteMap.subSection=smss;
        siteMapSection.Add(siteMap);
        }
```

Comment: so good. I see list of sections, subSections but not articles this is missing completely.

Comment: We're setting article property for each SiteMapSubSection. sms.article=sma; Make sure articles is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Initialize subSection in the constructor

```
public class SiteMapSection
{
   public string sectionUrl { get; set; }
   public List<SiteMapSubSection> subSection { get; set; }
   public SiteMapSection()
   {
        subSection    =new List<SiteMapSubSection>();
   }

 }
```

Comment: @AbhimanyuKumarVatsa subSection is 0 because the List is empty.This is a new object is has no subSections